# "No Suitable Driver" error for basic java derby DB read

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I am getting the following error from a basic java derby DB program using netbeans.

I have tried downloading many types of driver containing jar files and then changing the `Class.forName(_______);` statement to include the path with no luck. I have read many similar questions and attempted the resolutions with no luck.

When I go to services/database, then right click on the DB and click properties, it says

> Driver Class: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.

I can find the `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver` file under `project/libraries`, but only under the jar I recently added through right clicking the `app/properties/libraries/OK`, not sure where it is in the jdk 1.8.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

> Error: "SQL Error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample 0 08001"

```
    package javaapplication10;

    import java.sql.*;

    public class JavaApplication10 {

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample";
    try (
       Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
           data, "app", "APP");
       Statement st = conn.createStatement()) {

       Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");

        ResultSet rec = st.executeQuery(
            "select CUSTOMER_ID, NAME, CITY, STATE " +
            "from APP.CUSTOMER " +
            "order by CUSTOMER_ID");
        while (rec.next()) {
            System.out.println("CUSTOMER_ID:\t"
                + rec.getString(1));
            System.out.println("NAME:\t" + rec.getString(2));
            System.out.println("CITY:\t" + rec.getString(3));
            System.out.println("STATE:\t" + rec.getString(4));
            System.out.println();
        }
        st.close();
       } catch (SQLException s) {
        System.out.println("SQL Error: " + s.toString() + " "
            + s.getErrorCode() + " " + s.getSQLState());
       } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e.toString()
            + e.getMessage());
       }
       }
       }
```

[image: libraries image]

Comment: `derbyclient` can only be used if you are connecting to a running Derby _server_ somewhere (it's **only** a JDBC driver). Did you start a Derby server before you tried connection? If you want to use it as an embedded database then you need to use `derby.jar` (which contains the database engine) and a different URL

Comment: The Derby jars are no longer part of the JDK as of 1.8 (they used to be bundled in the JDK). Also, Derby 10.1 is **ancient** -- do not use it! Try downloading Derby 10.14 and putting derbyclient.jar into your CLASSPATH.

Comment: Thank you guys. The derbyclient.jar worked.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move line `Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");` outside of the try block (before the try clock). You can have the main method declare `throws ClassNotFoundException` for the program to compile. That way the drivers will be available for the DriverManager inside the `try` to find and use.

Also, since you are creating the Statement inside the try definition, the the last line `st.close();` before the `catch` is redundant, so you safely remove it.